# show percentage indicator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, progress-bar, flutter-animation, indicator

Maximum dates that show in that percentage indicator was 20

If my current pending day is 10 then it will be show like half of the progress bar.

how can I show like this?

Sample code here:

```
    class _ApplyLeaveState extends State<ApplyLeave> {
  double percent = 20.0;
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .height;
    double width = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: SideBar(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(app_leave),
        ),
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                      radius: 100.0,
                      lineWidth: 15.0,
                      percent: 0.6,
                        center:  Text(
                          leave_pending,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                      progressColor: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

I have tried this code?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that you've tried

Answer (score 0):

The logic will be

```dart
CircularProgressIndicator(
  value: currentDay / maxDay,
),
Text("${maxDay - currentDay}d"),
```

You can play with widget.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int currentDay = 10;
  int maxDay = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            currentDay++;
          });
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: currentDay / maxDay,
                  ),
                  Align(
                    child: Text("${maxDay - currentDay}d"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 `    static const EventChannel _channel = EventChannel('video_editor_progress');    `    


late StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;
 int processPercentage = 0; 




  void initState() {
_enableEventReceiver();
super.initState();}   


 void _enableEventReceiver() {
_streamSubscription =
    _channel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((dynamic event) {
  setState(() {
    processPercentage = (event.toDouble() * 100).round();
  });
}, onError: (dynamic error) {
  log('Received error: ${error.message}');
}, cancelOnError: true);};




void loadingStart(){
setState(() => processPercentage = 0);};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).